# Swift 4 get Bool result from "perform" function call

Tags: swift, selector

I've got a function like this in Swift:

```
@objc func doSomeStuff(_ args: [String]) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

And I have a selector name in String variable to execute. Here's my initial values:

```
let sel = Selector("doSomeStuff:")
let args = ["123123", "qweqweqwe"]
```

The problem is when I'm trying to receive the function calculation result like this:

```
let returnedValue = perform(sel, with: args)
```

Since that place I don't know how to get boolean value from `returnedValue` variable. Things I've already tried:

- to pass an `inout Bool` parameter to set it inside the function
- to pass an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Bool>` to set in function
- to get `returnedValue.takeRetainedValue()`

All of the above failed. So, how am I supposed handle this situation?

Comment: Where do you want the value of returned variable?

Comment: What is the result of `returnedValue` you get right now? Why don't you just call it as a normal function anyway in this case?

Comment: I'm getting the name of function as a string and in that place it's not possible to call it directly, kind of architectural solution. I'm not going to discuss it here, but believe me, I can not do it in another way) "doSomeStuff:" is there just for example. Just imagine such a situation)

Comment: In many years of Objective-C I used that `perform` method exactly once and removed the usage as soon as I learned to use blocks. Are you absolutely sure you want to use that type-unsafe method? Especially in Swift?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I also used to call perfromSelector method in Obj-C and I know  that it's kind of workaround, but in that situation I have no choice since it's cross-platform app using config file, where function names are listed as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the ObjC runtime consider that you are dealing with **objects**. The ObjC signature is *performSelector:with**Object**:*

In Swift you have to return a reference type `NSNumber` instance rather than value type `Bool`

```
@objc func doSomeStuff(_ args: [String]) -> NSNumber  {
    return NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true)
}
```

and you have to dereference the pointer

```
let result = perform(sel, with: args)
let number = result!.takeUnretainedValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let obj = classType.perform(selector)
    if let obj = obj as? AnyObject {
        let pointer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer = Unmanaged<AnyObject>.passUnretained(obj).toOpaque()
        let valueBool: Bool = pointer.load(as: Bool.self)
        return valueBool
    }
    return false
```